# Does the relationship between definiteness and specificity vary across languages?

Tags: syntax, morphology

In English, specificity of reference and the use of definite vs. indefinite articles don't always co-vary.

For example, in "A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush," and "The bird is the only living feathered creature," both "a bird" and "the bird" have non-specific reference.

However, in "A bird came to my window one day," and "The bird pecked at my cat's head," both "a bird" and "the bird" have specific reference.

But does the apparent independence of specificity and definiteness hold true across languages?  (Does it even always hold true in English?)

Comment: In "The bird is the only living feathered creature", isn't "the bird" referring to a specific class of living creatures, or do I have the definitions wrong?

Comment: There's a whole lot more than specificity and definiteness involved. There's also [genericity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), as well as [the _de re/de dicto_ and referential/attributive distinctions, not to mention referential opacity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/someproblemsofreference.pdf). And yes, they all vary quite a lot from language to language. Definiteness is required of direct objects, for instance, in Turkish.

Comment: @dainichi:   Well, as I understand it, if a term refers to a whole class of things rather than one or more individuals, that term is non-specific.

Comment: @jlawler:  Thanks for your many helpful comments.